# When accessing current instance of Lync running on localhost by Windows service, I get the exception "host process is not running"

Tags: c#, lync

I am accessing current instance of Lync running in my local computer by window service.
I have installed windows service which executes exe, this exe access the current instance of lync and when i was running this service, it gives exception

> host process is not running exception message: 
>   Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.EnsureOI()
>      at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient(Boolean sideBySideLync)

Also I am running the service as the same user that's running the lync.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.  The service user session is not the same as the local desktop user session.  That is why service applications can't create UI (any longer), is the same reason you can't access Lync.exe as Lync.exe is not running in your service users session.  If it did, you would not be able to see it as it would run in the service session.

You have to run your application as a normal desktop application.  It doesn't have to have a UI, it can run in background.